# Shell doesn't cover the entire inner wall at some areas

Tags: ultimaker-cura

How do I improve/increase shell coverage so that it covers the entire inner wall?
I've experimented with shell settings, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm using Creality Slicer 4.2.1 (Cura)

Picture showing the areas in question below:
[image: Areas in question highlighted with blue boxes]

Comment: Green is "top" red is "wall".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the top layer thickness [according to Ultimaker Cura support](https://support.ultimaker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012512340-Shell-settings):

> ## Top/bottom thickness
>
> With the top/bottom thickness you can set the thickness of the solidly printed top and bottom layers of the print. A higher value ensures all gaps on the top and bottom layers are closed completely. However, this can also increase the print time and amount of filament used.
>
> It is advised to always use a multiple of the layer height for the thickness of the top and bottom. This means, for example, that with a layer height of 0.15 mm, it’s better to set the top/bottom thickness to 0.6 mm rather than 0.7 mm.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with top layer thickness, but I can't seem to get that single top layer to cover the entire curved shell.

Comment: @bigpow What do you mean? A single layer instead of the multiple layers? That is not simple, it is called non-planar slicing, see e.g. [this website](https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/research/3d-printing/nonplanar_printing/index.php).

Comment: Thanks. I'm new. I don't understand what I don't know. I thought it would require editing the original 3D model to increase the poly # (to smoothen the gradation), but then again, that probably be printable since the printer resolution is fixed. Another rabbit hole.